# Alias methods from association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this is a very simple question, but googling only returns me info about relationship basics and method chaining.. What is the `class method` called to alias for example `user.profile.name` to `user.name`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate):

```rb
delegate :name, :to => :profile
```

Comment: Also u can add option `prefix: true` or another value, And `allow_nil: true` (if user has no profile then return nil instead of undefined method `name` for nil:NilClass)